# Unshare and port forwarding into namespace

Tags: network-namespace

I am playing with `unshare` to better understand containers. As a normal user, is it possible to make a namespace where a program could listen, say, port `123` and on the "main" namespace a port `1234` would be redirected to it?

I guess it should be, as Podman is rootless container engine and can do it. Looking `man veth` did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podman works by using [slirp4netns](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns) to manage a [tap device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) inside the unprivileged container. From the README for slirp4netns:

> Starting with Linux 3.8, unprivileged users can create `network_namespaces(7)` along with `user_namespaces(7)`. However, unprivileged network namespaces had not been very useful, because creating `veth(4)` pairs across the host and network namespaces still requires the root privileges. (i.e. No internet connection)
>
> slirp4netns allows connecting a network namespace to the Internet in a completely unprivileged way, by connecting a TAP device in a network namespace to the usermode TCP/IP stack ("slirp").

In order to achieve your goal, you would need to do something similar.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But still, how to connect a "host" port `X` to a "namespace" port `Y`?

Comment: You run a process that listens on a port on the host and proxies connections into the container. Podman uses [rootlessport](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/3a46fe858f3f2956e7a8b9f340f0a8ed187d2593/cmd/rootlessport/main.go) for this.